# Should I authorize users based on their SID or their Windows Username?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, active-directory, windows-authentication

I am creating a C# DotNet Application that authorizes users using their **windows active directory ID**.

Windows users have 2 unique identifiers

- The Username **(e.g. MyDomain\someuser)**
- The SID **(e.g. S-1-5-21-1695517229-881958489-217698969-1001**

**QUESTION:** In my back end should I authorize users based on their **SID** or **Windows Username**?

What's the best practice?

**Here are my thought so far:**

- The SIDs are unique but some newbie can delete and create a new Active Directory ID. This will cause the user to have different SID and unable to login
- As for the username, I'm worried it can be spoofed. Not sure if such is possible though.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm worried it can be spoofed

What do you mean by "spoofed"? You're going to be connecting to only one domain, and only one account on any domain can have the same username.

Even if you decide to authenticate by SID, you're not going to ask the user for their SID, so you'll have to translate the username into the SID anyway, which means you're still authenticating with a username.

But remember you don't just authenticate with a username. You authenticate with a username *and* password.

Everything else in the world uses a username and password, including Windows itself. So use that.